# MySQL statement python escape single quote '

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, character, mysql-error-1064

I have below MySQL statement with python but there is a single quote ' in one of the values hence I got below error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near L at line 1
```

The value to be inserted is Regal INT'L

How to escape or to correct the MySQL statement?

MySQL statement

```
def query(self, item):

        return "INSERT INTO income_statement({columns}) VALUES ({values})".format(

            columns=', '.join(item.keys()),

            values=self.item_to_text(item)

        )

def item_to_text(self, item):
        return ', '.join("'" + str(v) + "'" for v in item.values()
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a tuple of string template and tuple of variables and the cursor can execute (template, (v1,v2,..))

```
cursor.execute(‘insert into tablename (c, d) values (%s, %s)’, (v1, v2))
```

Based on the [API Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

Edit 2: A more complete example

```
def query(self, item):
  values = ', '.join(['%s']*len(item.keys()))
  stmt = "INSERT INTO income_statement({columns}) VALUES ({values})".format(
      columns=', '.join(item.keys()),
      values=values
  )
  # self.item_to_text(item) must be a tuple
  return (stmt, self.item_to_text(item))

# use it like so
cursor.execute(query(item))
```

Edit 3:
I am pretty certain that if you really want to pass the statement as a single string you’d have to have a \ present in the string itself thus using
    INT\\’L

Edit 4:

```
def item_to_text(self, item):
    return ', '.join(item.values()) # assuming item.values() returns a list or a tuple
```

Comment: I have not gotten a chance to test it yet, but it should work based on the api docs.

Comment: Thank you Khnanal, I updated my question with the 'item_to_text' function, does the %s means to escape the ' ? In my updated question, where/how to put the escape in the join statement?

Comment: Oh you don't need to escape it at all on the item_to_text, assuming it is a list of strings. basically %s would let mysql know that it is expecting a string and then it will escape the string it gets in.

Comment: Thanks very much Khanal!

Comment: Glad it helped you!

Comment: would you also help to take a look at my this questions?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000140/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-with-all-variables?noredirect=1#comment88994845_51000140